# Read the xml response received from navison and bind the response in mvc model and display in table

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, xml-parsing, navision

I need to access an url and get the xml response (tags contain colon in it) and bind the response in model class and display it in an html table.

So far I have accessed the url,read the xml and my problem is I am not able to bind the data in my model class as there is colon in the tags,without colon I am able to do easily,I have read that using name space is the way but I am new to this and not able to implement the logic.Any help will be very thankful.

P.S : I am using mvc,c#,razor view

```
          //this will read the url and get back xml response and save it
          string xml = null;
          WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("my__xml__link__url");
          req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
          WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
          Stream dataStream = res.GetResponseStream();
          StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
          xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
          reader.Close();
          res.Close();
          int length = 8;
          const string valid = 
          "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
           StringBuilder resz = new StringBuilder();
           Random rnd = new Random();
           while (0 < length--)
           {
            resz.Append(valid[rnd.Next(valid.Length)]);
           }
           string sf = DateTime.Now.ToString();
           string generatedresult = resz.ToString() + "_" + ".xml";
           XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
           try
           {
            doc.LoadXml(xml);
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
             string dgj = ex.ToString();
           }
            doc.Save(@"D:\" + generatedresult + "");


         //this below code to read the data and bind it in the model and 
          //displayit in the html table


        List<CustomerModel> customers = new List<CustomerModel>();
        //Load the XML file in XmlDocument.
        doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/oWtMRUR8_.xml"));
        foreach (XmlNode node in 
             doc.SelectNodes("/m:propertiesz/m:properties"))
            {
            customers.Add(new CustomerModel
            {
                CustomerId = int.Parse(node["d:No"].InnerText),
                Name = node["d:Description"].InnerText,
                Country = node["d:Type"].InnerText
            });
             }
             return View(customers);

       // I have attached my sample xml code 


      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <feed xml:base="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="" 
       xmlns:m="">
       <id></id>
    <title type="text">ItemList</title>
       <updated>2019-05-08T12:10:04Z</updated>
     <link rel="self" title="ItemList" href="ItemList" />
              <id></id>
         <category term="NAV.ItemList" scheme="" />
         <link rel="edit" title="ItemList" href="" />
        <title />
           <updated>2019-05-08T12:10:04Z</updated>
           <author>
         <name />
             </author>
            <content type="application/xml">
         <m:properties>
            <d:No>1000</d:No>
             <d:Description>Bicycle</d:Description>
         <d:Type>Inventory</d:Type>
         </m:properties>
         </content>


             <id></id>
             <category term="NAV.ItemList" scheme="" />
              <link rel="edit" title="ItemList" href="" />
           <title />
            <updated>2019-05-08T12:10:04Z</updated>
              <author>
              <name />
              </author>
             <content type="application/xml">
              <m:properties>
              <d:No>1001</d:No>
            <d:Description>Touring Bicycle</d:Description>
            <d:Type>Inventory</d:Type>
            </m:properties>
             </content>
```

I need to extract only the contents inside  the d: tag.
Note: I have slightly editted the sample xml content due to privacy reasons

Answer (score 0):

You should use overloaded version of [SelectNodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_XmlNode_SelectNodes_System_String_System_Xml_XmlNamespaceManager_). The second parameter should be the namespace manager with your namespaces.